# Angular - RxJs - why does code execute at the end?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, subscription, rxjs-observables

I'm having trouble getting the code inside a subscribe to run before my components load on my Angular Application.

In my application I have a service which handles both login and permissions with 2 different functions.

```
login(email: string, password: string): Observable<UserType> {
    this.isLoadingSubject.next(true);
    // Llamo a la API con las credenciales
    return this.http.post<Usuario>(`${Constants.urlBase}/auth/signin`, {email: email, password: password}).pipe(
      mergeMap((user: any) => {
        debugger
        // Si obtengo el usuario
        if (user) {
          this.usuario = user
          this.rolesByID(user.id,user.token)
          
          //*Fuerzo el lenguaje español
          user.language = 'es';          

          //*Guardo el usuario en el storage
          this.setAuthFromLocalStorage(user);

          //*Memorizo el user actual
          this.currentUserSubject.next(user);
          
        } else {
          this.logout();
        }

        return of(user);
      }),
      catchError((err) => {
        console.error('err', err);
        return of(undefined);
      }),
      finalize(() => this.isLoadingSubject.next(false))
    );
  }
```

As you can see, when the code inside the if statement executes, it triggers the following function, which is also inside the same service:

```
  rolesByID(userID:any,token:any){
    this.userService.rolesByID(userID,token).subscribe({
      next:(rol) => {
        rol.forEach((element:any) => {
          
          sessionStorage.setItem("Rol", JSON.stringify(userID));
          if(element.funcion.nombre == "Alarmas"){
            sessionStorage.setItem("Alarmas", JSON.stringify(element));
          }
          if(element.funcion.nombre == "Clientes"){
            sessionStorage.setItem("Clientes", JSON.stringify(element));
          }
          if(element.funcion.nombre == "Establecimientos"){
            sessionStorage.setItem("Establecimientos", JSON.stringify(element));
          }
          if(element.funcion.nombre == "Estadisticas"){
            sessionStorage.setItem("Estadisticas", JSON.stringify(element));
          }
          if(element.funcion.nombre == "Perfiles"){
            sessionStorage.setItem("Perfiles", JSON.stringify(element));
          }
          if(element.funcion.nombre == "Sensores"){
            sessionStorage.setItem("Sensores", JSON.stringify(element));
          }
          if(element.funcion.nombre == "Usuarios"){
            sessionStorage.setItem("Usuarios", JSON.stringify(element));
          }
        });
        console.log(sessionStorage.getItem("Usuarios"))
        debugger
        //location.reload();
        }})
  }
```

But somehow, the code inside  "next:(rol)", only executes after the last of the components has been initialized. Which is a problem for me because I need the user permissions information for some menu items validations I'm trying to get to work.

(Sorry for the comments in Spanish!)

Comment: If you need to wait for `rolesById` to do something before `setAuthFromLocalStorage`, consider adding an event listener so you can wait for changes in storage to happen first and put `setAuthFromLocalStorage` in the callback, e.g. `window.addEventListener('storage', () => {set auth here})`.

Comment: @possum It's somewhere along those lines, yes. There is a layout component which initializes (among other components) an asideMenuComponent which needs the sessionStorageData to validate if the user has permissions to see certain menu items or not. Thing is, my application is only setting the sessionData after all the other components have already loaded/initialized. I will try to make it work with your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to return `this.userService.rolesByID()` within concatMap resp. mergeMap, so that this call will be awaited before `this.setAuthFromLocalStorage(user)` is invoked:

```
login(email: string, password: string): Observable<UserType> {
    this.isLoadingSubject.next(true);
    // Llamo a la API con las credenciales
    return this.http.post<Usuario>(`${Constants.urlBase}/auth/signin`, {email: email, password: password}).pipe(
      concatMap((user: any) => {
        debugger
        // Si obtengo el usuario
        if (user) {
          this.usuario = user         

          // This part is crucial:
          return this.userService.rolesByID(user.id,user.token).pipe(
            tap(() => {         
              //*Fuerzo el lenguaje español
              user.language = 'es'; 
            
              //*Guardo el usuario en el storage
              this.setAuthFromLocalStorage(user);

              //*Memorizo el user actual
              this.currentUserSubject.next(user);                       
            }),
            map(() => user)
          );                  
        } else {
          this.logout();
          return of(null);
        }
      }),
      catchError((err) => {
        console.error('err', err);
        return of(undefined);
      }),
      finalize(() => this.isLoadingSubject.next(false))
    );
  }
```

Comment: `rolesByID` doens't return anything.  You could subscribe to it if it returned the subscription using `addChildSubscription`

Comment: At the end of the pipe of `rolesByID()` I take the user-object from above (from `concatMap((user: any)`) and return it, so that the final return value of `login()` remains `Observable<UserType>`. This does actually work, even though there are other possibilities for sure. And my example ensures the order of calls: 1.) `rolesByID()`, 2.) `this.setAuthFromLocalStorage()`

Comment: Yes, and I'm telling you if you read the code for `rolesByID` and it is *not* an observable so you cannot call `rolesByID().pipe` unless you change `rolesByID` which you didn't do in your answer.  `rolesByID` as written is a `void` function.

Comment: Ah sorry, I got confused since the component-method and the service method are both named `rolesByID()`. Now I return `this.userService.rolesByID()` which should be fine.

Comment: I'll clarify a bit @possum @kellermat: `this.userService.rolesByID()` refers to a different function on a different service which only returns the http response as an observable. That response is in turn, handled by  `rolesById()` on the service shown in my question (auth.service.ts).